# Sencha Touch Issue with Stores

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a store defined that I want to manually add data to. The store is connected to a model with the proper fields defined and the store is instantiated.

Why does this work

```
Ext.getStore('Inspections').add({"code":"123","descr":"Inspection 123"});
```

Why does this not work

```
Ext.getStore('Inspections').loadData([{"code":"123","descr":"Inspection 123"}]);
```

I get `LoadData not defined error.`

Answer (score 3):

Because `loadData` is not a method on Store: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store

What you want is [setData](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-setData).